# How to set file permission for multiple users in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-permissions

I have a file `format.sh` in *linux os*.

There are five users `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` & `e`.

How can I set the file permission for different users:

- `a` -> Read, Write & Execute
- `b` -> Read & Execute
- `c` -> Read
- `d` -> Execute
- `e` -> No permission

I have familiarity with basic file permissions modification using `chmod`, `chown` & `chgrp` but I'm not sure how to give permissions for different users to a single file?

Comment: Does `.sh` mean it's a shell script? See [*Can a script be executable but not readable?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34202/108618)

Comment: Check ACL: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-access-control-lists

Comment: Are you able to set up a group for the authorised users?   Do you have local root access ?

Comment: @Criggie please see the link provided by @Romeo. The `setfacl`(**set** **f**ile **a**ccess **c**ontrol **l**ist) and `getfacl`(**get** **f**ile **a**ccess **c**ontrol **l**ist) commands are useful in setting access for different users. In order to use `setfacl` and `getfacl` commands first install `acl` (**a**ccess **c**ontrol **l**ist) package by `sudo apt install acl` command

Comment: @Udesh back in the dark ages before ACLs, we had `"groups"` which are noted in `/etc/groups` and different users could be part of different groups.  By default a user needs to be in `dialout` to control a serial port, etc.   Concept of groups is decades-old, but do require root access to edit.   Hence the clarification of "do you have root?" before I post an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested by Romeo Ninov, you can define complex permissions for a file using ACLs (Access Control Lists), **if your filesystem supports them**.

For instance, you can define the permissions in your question with:

```
setfacl -m u:a:rwx,u:b:r-x,u:c:r--,u:d:--x,u:e:--- format.sh
```

You can also check the permissions for a file with:

```
getfacl format.sh
```

If user `a` is also the owner of the `format.sh` file, you may set use standard permissions for that user rather than list her in the ACL.

You should note that, as explained by Kamil Maciorowski’s comment, it is useless to give a user permission to execute a script without giving her permission to read it. You may also consider that a user who can read a program but not execute it might copy the program and give herself permission to execute her copy.

Comment: About read only file: instead of copy you can do something like `bash format.sh` and you will get the script executed :)

Comment: One additional thing worth pointing out: Using ACLs changes what the displayed group permissions in many file listing tools represent (instead of showing primary group permissions, they essentially show what you would get by doing a bitwise OR of all the ACL permission bits).